# AffineTransform a CGPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpoint, affinetransform

I've been doing research all morning. No luck so far. I'm trying to rotate a CGPoint around the center of my view.

Here's what I do for UIBezierPath:

```
CGRect bounds = self.bounds; // might want to use CGPathGetPathBoundingBox
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, center.x, center.y);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degreesOfRotation));
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -center.x, -center.y);
currentLayer.path = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(pathTwo.CGPath, &transform);
```

It work's *great*. I found this post [What is the best way to rotate a CGPoint on a grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595285/what-is-the-best-way-to-rotate-a-cgpoint-on-a-grid) and it just didn't work.

I really need a way to rotate CGPoint around the center of my bounds.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to calculate the transform is correct. All you need to do is apply the transform to the point.

```
CGRect bounds = self.bounds;
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, center.x, center.y);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degreesOfRotation));
transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -center.x, -center.y);

CGPoint point = CGPointMake(bounds.size.width - 10, center.y);  // some point
CGPoint point2 = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(point, transform); // some point rotated about the center of the view
```