# Swift: make rotation of point in 2D

Tags: ios, swift, math, rotation, cgpoint

I want to make a rotation of point by -90 degrees

Initial

[image: https://ibb.co/HHCCSyp]

Final

[image: https://ibb.co/3vyV7PG]

Let's take a look on top left and top right points of Initial. Their coordinates are:

```
let topLeft = CGPoint(x: 2, y: 1)  
let topRight = CGPoint(x: 3, y: 1)
```

And after rotation coordinates of them should become:

```
topLeft 1:0
topRight 2:0
```

How can i do it ?

I have tried several answers but none of them give me my final results.

did not work:
[Rotating a CGPoint around another CGPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683376/rotating-a-cgpoint-around-another-cgpoint)

[What is the best way to rotate a CGPoint on a grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595285/what-is-the-best-way-to-rotate-a-cgpoint-on-a-grid)

Here are some code from my playground:

```
 let topLeft = CGPoint(x: 2, y: 1)   
 let topRight = CGPoint(x: 3, y: 1)  

 func rotatePoint1(_ point: CGPoint, _ degrees: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
     let s = CGFloat(sinf(Float(degrees)))
     let c = CGFloat(cosf(Float(degrees)));
     return CGPoint(x: c * point.x - s * point.y, y: s * point.x + c * point.y)
 }

 func rotatePoint2(_ point: CGPoint, _ degrees: CGFloat, _ origin: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
     let dx = point.x - origin.x
     let dy = point.y - origin.y
     let radius = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
     let azimuth = atan2(dy, dx) // in radians
     let newAzimuth = azimuth + degrees * CGFloat(M_PI / 180.0) // convert it to radians
     let x = origin.x + radius * cos(newAzimuth)
     let y = origin.y + radius * sin(newAzimuth)
     return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
 }

 func rotatePoint3(_ point: CGPoint, _ degrees: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
     let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: point.x, y: point.y)
     let rotationTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degrees)
     let customRotation = (rotationTransform.concatenating(translateTransform.inverted())).concatenating(translateTransform)
     return point.applying(customRotation)
 }

 print(rotatePoint1(topLeft, -90))
 print(rotatePoint1(topRight, -90))
```

Comment: Your `topLeft` becomes bottom left (1:1) after rotation by -90 about center point (and topRight  becomes top left), so it is worth to specify problem more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are really describing two rotations with your example:

1. The points are rotated by -90 degrees around the center of the 3x3 grid.  When this happens, the `topLeft` point becomes `bottomLeft`, and `topRight` becomes `topLeft`.
2. Then you rotate those points around the center of the square 90 degrees (ie. the other direction) to make them `topLeft` and `topRight` again.

Using this function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35683523/1630618):

```
func rotatePoint(target: CGPoint, aroundOrigin origin: CGPoint, byDegrees: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    let dx = target.x - origin.x
    let dy = target.y - origin.y
    let radius = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
    let azimuth = atan2(dy, dx) // in radians
    let newAzimuth = azimuth + byDegrees * .pi / 180 // convert it to radians
    let x = origin.x + radius * cos(newAzimuth)
    let y = origin.y + radius * sin(newAzimuth)
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}

let topLeft = CGPoint(x: 2, y: 1)
let topRight = CGPoint(x: 3, y: 1)
let squareCenter = CGPoint(x: 2.5, y: 1.5)

// First rotate around the center of the 3 x 3 square
let centerOfRotation = CGPoint(x: 1.5, y: 1.5)

let tl1 = rotatePoint(target: topLeft, aroundOrigin: centerOfRotation, byDegrees: -90)  // (x 1 y 1)
let tr1 = rotatePoint(target: topRight, aroundOrigin: centerOfRotation, byDegrees: -90) // (x 1 y 0)
let sc1 = rotatePoint(target: squareCenter, aroundOrigin: centerOfRotation, byDegrees: -90)  // (x 1.5 y 0.5)

// Now rotate the 1x1 square the other way around new position of square center
let tl2 = rotatePoint(target: tl1, aroundOrigin: sc1, byDegrees: 90)  // (x 1 y 0)
let tr2 = rotatePoint(target: tr1, aroundOrigin: sc1, byDegrees: 90)  // (x 2 y 0)
```

**Note:** As @MBo noted in the comments, if your cell is always 1x1, it is sufficient to rotate the center of your cell and then just add and subtract the `0.5` offsets to find the four corners.

Comment: @vacawame thank you, this is what i need, now i see why all my tries failed. Thank you so much. One more thing, how can i make it for bottom left and bottom right?

Comment: @vacawama Seems you understood author's needs right. Just note - it is enough to use a single rotation - rotate center of small cell, then add offsets of corners.

Comment: @MBo, that is correct.  If the cell is always 1x1, you could just rotate the center and add the offsets.  I was trying to keep it general in case they later rotated cells of other sizes and dimensions.

Comment: `squareCenter` is based upon the square you are rotating.  You can use `topRight.x - topLeft.x` to compute the dimensions and add half of that to `topLeft.x` and `topLeft.y` to find the `squareCenter`.  If you are asking about a larger grid, the center of rotation is just `(gridWidth/2.0, gridHeight/2.0)`.

Comment: @vacawama I've been struggling for a while with a very similar issue. I want to convert a CGPoint from landscape to its corresponding portrait location and vice versa after orientation changes. In other words the point should say in the exact same location. Can you take a look at my attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You can just transform you view like so

`yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi/2)`

EDIT:
My bad.

Use `CGFloat.pi` when working with degrees

`print(rotatePoint1(topLeft, -CGFloat.pi/2))`

Use sin and cos functions directly

```
let s = sin(degrees)
let c = cos(degrees)
```

iOS coordinate system is a bit flipped compared to standard one so you will have to adjust the angle (you can see [simulation](https://academo.org/demos/rotation-about-point/))

```
print(rotatePoint1(topLeft, -CGFloat.pi/2)) // (1.0000000000000002, -2.0)
print(rotatePoint1(topRight, -CGFloat.pi/2)) // (1.0000000000000002, -3.0)
```

Comment: hey, the output is not correct, please check images in my post: topLeft will be 1:0, topRight 2:0